# Sum of all the numbers with the given numbers repeated

Tags: summation, permutations, combinations

How to find the sum of all the numbers that can be formed using the digits **4,5,5,6,6,6** (This includes 4,5,6,45,46,54,55,....,666554). I knew that the answer is **39345806**. I just need to know the method for finding it.

I tried using the formula from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1102338/sum-of-all-the-numbers-that-can-be-formed-using-the-digits-2-3-3-4-4-4) but I am not able to obtain that answer.

Sum of 1 digit numbers : 32*1*1 = 32

Sum of 2 digit numbers : 32*1*11 = 352

Sum of 3 digit numbers : 32*2*111 = 7104

Sum of 4 digit numbers : 32*6*1111 = 213312

Sum of 5 digit numbers : 32*24*11111 = 8533248

Sum of 6 digit numbers : 32*120*111111 = 426666240

Sum of all numbers = $Sum of all the above sum/2!3!$
     = $435420288/12$
     =**36285024**

Can anyone please give me an explanation on where I went wrong?

Comment: Why isn´t $54$ possible ?

Comment: yes 54 is also possible. It includes 54 too. I just gave a glance of possible numbers.

Comment: Reason for the downvote? I have put some effort before posting here. Or else is the question unclear?

Comment: We people can downvote whenever we feel like it. It's better, but absolutely not required, to give a reason.

Comment: $45+46+54+55+56+64+65+66=91+165+195=91+360=451$, so I'm not sure where you get $352$.

Comment: So, how do you get 352, where I get 451?

Comment: Yes we get 451 if we manually add all the numbers. But by using the formula which I mentioned above , we get 352. I am not sure how that formula does not suit my requirement? @GerryMyerson

Comment: I am not sure why you think the formula $32\times1\times11$ should work. You give no reasoning behind it, and the question you link to has nothing like it.

Comment: Sorry if I was wrong. Can you please explain me the difference between my problem and that of the question I have linked?@GerryMyerson

Comment: I see no difference between your problem and the one you have linked (except of course that the digits are different). Now please answer my question: why do you think $32\times1\times11$ should work?

Comment: Am very sorry. I misinterepted the formula $(sum of all digits)×(n-1)!×(11..n)$, which can only be used to find the sum of the numbers formed by using all the n digits. Now I understood that it cannot be used to form numbers containing less than n digits. In such cases I guess (n-1)! must be replaced with Permutation of numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Merely a start, too long for a comment.]

If you just look at the six-digit numbers, first, you have that half have a six as the first digit, a third have a 5 as the first digit, and a sixth have a 4 as the first digit.

So that means the average digit in the first digit is $\frac{1}{2}\cdot 6 +\frac{1}{3}\cdot 5 +\frac{1}{6}\cdot 4=\frac{16}{3}$. The same is true for each digit in a six-digit number, so the average number is $\frac{16}{3}\cdot 111111$.

The total count of such numbers is $\frac{6!}{3!2!1!}=\frac{6\cdot 5\cdot 4}{2}=60$. So the total is $320\cdot 111111$.

The lower number of digits is harder. It is both harder to compute the average and the count.

Comment: Am really sorry. I could not understand your explanation.

Comment: how are you dividing the halves?

Comment: What halves? @ArunKumar

Comment: Here the sum of the digits is 32. But why are you reducing it to 16/3?

Comment: the average digit is $\frac{32}{6}=\frac{16}{3}$. @ArunKumar